# NGINX Reverse Proxy : Is it possible to proxy cache ONLY 404 (or other) html status codes?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, cache

With nginx, latest, is it possible to proxy cache ONLY specific html status code responses?

We use 410 status codes for some responses.

These are checked against our database.

When the said content is flagged as removed for ever (410), a 410 status code is sent.

This content is gone forever.

We would like to proxy cache ONLY these results.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use proxy_cache_valid directive, e.g.:

```
proxy_cache_valid 410      1m;
proxy_cache_valid any      0;
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_valid

Comment: :) i knew about proxy_cache_valid, we use it for other stuff... but did not know we could pass a 0 value to any to avoid caching :) thanks!

Comment: not working for me. it still caches 301 responses. `proxy_cache_valid 200 1d;
proxy_cache_valid any 0;`

Comment: cache control/expires header are prioritized over proxy_cache timings. You can add proxy_ignore_header if you have such headers.

Comment: [`proxy_cache_valid 410 1m;` is enough. `0` for the `time` is not valid.](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?21,275049,275055#msg-275055)